# Generating random images to the height of another div. PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image, height

This code at the moment picks 6 random images from my images directory and places them in a sidebar for display. The problem is that I don't want the sidebar to display just 6 images, I want the sidebar to generate images to match the height of my main content div.

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < $imagesCount ; $i++) {

$randomIndex = array_rand($images); 

$file_title = $randomImage = $images[$randomIndex];
unset($images[$randomIndex]);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"><img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"
     width="100%" height="150%"; alt="" /> <br /><br /></a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Right now my idea was using jquery to find the height of the div and generating images until the value of the height is reached using something like this pseudo code: 
  `for($i = 0 ; $i < $("#content").height(); ; $i++) { 
 random images stuff here;
}`

The problem here (besides the fact that I am mixing JQuery and PHP which I would fix later) is that .height() is going to return me a value in pixels thus randomly generating 800-1200 random images. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this problem? Here is a link to the page so you can see what I mean if there is any confusion. [Link](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/standings.php)

Comment: jQuery should do one thing: get the height. It sounds like it is already doing this. php should do one thing: return images based on the height. The php accepts the height, and then calculates how many images to return.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want 800 random images, which is what that last code snippet would do. Somehow I need to figure out a way to add the heights of each randomly generated image and have more images generated until the height of the main div is less than the height of the added images. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really a lot of ways you can approach this but...

Use php to create your dom elements like so and pass them off to jQuery as a variable:

```
<?php

$images = howeverYourGettingYourSixImages();

for($i=0; $i<count($images); $i++){
    $image_array[]='<img  class="images" src="'.$images[$i].'"/>';
}

echo('<script type="text/javascript">var images='.json_encode($image_array).'</script>');
?>
```

somewhere in your body declare your container

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and before the body close execute the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var container = jQuery('#content');
    var container_height = container.height();
    var image_height = container_height / images.length;
    jQuery.each(images,function(k,v){
       container.append(v);
    });
    jQuery(".images").height(image_height);;

</script>
```

and to ensure your content container has a height and that the elements stack add some css to your head

```
<style type="text/css">
    #content{
            height: 600px;
    }
    .images{
            float:left;
            clear:both;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If you want to dynamically get the images with php: put the php in an external script and return the images array via AJAX instead of echoing the results like in the example. Let me know if thats what you're trying to do and I could show an example.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply with actual details on how I can approach this. The echo is working fine for me with the static 6 images. The real issue is just being able to determine when to stop generating images. If you check that link out. You will see that sometimes the 6 images are just way too much for the content of the page (which is already set to <div id="content">). It will take me a bit to apply your code to mine, but I will let you know if it works! I am a a JQuery newb for sure and prefer to stay in PHP land.